# How to display alphabetical list in ng2-ckeditor?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

CKEditor numbered list property changes are not displayed correctly in the ng2-ckeditor

Tried updating cdn url to "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.10.1/full/ckeditor.js"

Change numbered list properties type to "Lower Alpha", for example.

Expected results:
Numbered list is displayed as a,b,c

Actual results:
Numbered list is still displayed as 1,2,3

When going to the properties window of the numbered list again, the correct properties are shown.

Also, when going to the actual page on the site, it is displayed correctly with letters instead of numbers.

Comment: There is only diff in your Expected and Actual Result that is *`still`*

Comment: Same here! Can you please explain and provide code example